# Getting Selenium Webdriver exception : Unable to parse remote response: Parameters were incorrect

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I was trying to setup automation on macbook for android application using selenium webdriver and appium.

Here is my code :-

```
package com.tas.androidtest;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class MyFirstAppiumDroidTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    File appDir= new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/app");
       File app= new File(appDir, "selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");

       //declaring Andriod platform properties
       DesiredCapabilities capa = new DesiredCapabilities();
       capa.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
       capa.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
       capa.setCapability("platformName",MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
       capa.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
       capa.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendriod.testapp");
       capa.setCapability("appActivity","io.selendriod.testapp.HomeScreenActivity");

       //instantiating Andriod driver  
    AndroidDriver driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capa);
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.findElementById("io.selendroid.testapp:id/startUserRegistration").clear();
       driver.findElementById("io.selendroid.testapp:id/inputUsername").sendKeys("test");
       driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/inputEmail")).sendKeys("test@mail.com");
       driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/inputPassword")).sendKeys("12345");
       driver.hideKeyboard();
       driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/input_adds")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/btnRegisterUser")).click();
       Assert.assertEquals("napendra", driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/label_username_data")).getText());
       driver.quit();
       System.out.print("Completed !!!");

}

}
```

*I Have started the appium server and run the test using with maven but I am getting error everytime I run the test.*
**Here is the error :-**

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Unable to parse remote response: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted
>   {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]}
>   and you sent ["desiredCapabilities","capabilities"] Build info:
>   version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time:
>   '2017-11-06T21:01:39.354Z' System info: host:
>   'Users-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '192.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
>   os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:111)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:114)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:132)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:92)
>     at
>   com.tas.androidtest.MyFirstAppiumDroidTest.main(MyFirstAppiumDroidTest.java:52)

Comment: can you post the appium server logs ?

Comment: Well appium server logs looks fine, but yes please find the logs here

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 6 ms - 83 

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 8 ms - 83

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using later version of java-client in your tests and its incompatible with **1.5.3** server version.

I saw this error in some other reports and Appium server update solved it: [1.7.1](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases) is latest stable now.